# ext4 overrides my commit=100 mount option with commit=0

Tags: mount, ext4

Here is the relevant line from my /etc/fstab file:

```
UUID=f51aa298-9ce4-4a19-a323-10df333f34f5 /               ext4    data=writeback,noatime,barrier=0,errors=remount-ro,commit=100,nobh,nouser_xattr       0       1
```

Here is what happens when I type the command "mount":

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=writeback,barrier=0,errors=remount-ro,commit=100,nobh,nouser_xattr,commit=0)
```

Why does it specify "commit=0" at the end? Does it mean that my commit=100 option is not used?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10, 32-bit with the latest updates.

Comment: What does `grep ' / ' /proc/mounts` show? The information in `/proc/mounts` comes directly from the kernel, whereas `mount` uses information in `/etc/mtab`, which might not be up-to-date for `/`.

Comment: /dev/disk/by-uuid/f51aa298-9ce4-4a19-a323-10df333f34f5 / ext4 rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=0,nobh,data=writeback 0 0

Comment: @Gilles - Why would /etc/mtab become out of date? Curious.

Comment: @boehj `/etc/mtab` is updated by `mount`, if it can. `/` is normally mounted read-only by the kernel or the initrd/initramfs, the remounted read-write as part of the boot process. I'm not sure if the final mount options (from `/etc/fstab`) are always recorded correctly.

Comment: @Gilles - Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.
It seems the problem was with the `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/journal-commit` file.  I edited the above file as root and changed the line

```
JOURNAL_COMMIT_TIME_AC=${JOURNAL_COMMIT_TIME_AC:-0}
```

to be

```
JOURNAL_COMMIT_TIME_AC=${JOURNAL_COMMIT_TIME_AC:-100}
```

And that's all!

P.S - I have no idea why the script ignores conflicting mount options. I believe it should check for user-specified options and not override them.

Comment: That's not a good solution. Next time you update your `pm-utils` (or whatever owns that file, I'm not an Ubuntu guy) your script may be hosed.

The `${JOURNAL_COMMIT_TIME_AC:-100}` is a `bash` thing that says if `JOURNAL_COMMIT_TIME_AC` is NOT defined, set it to 100. So you need to set that value somewhere that the script reads it. In RedHat systems, it would be somewhere in `/etc/sysconfig/` - you need to trace the script and see where it would have read it from.

Comment: Oh, and as for ignoring the `/etc/fstab` entry, that would be a bug report against the software. Unless there is a distro-specific setup program you were *supposed* to use that would have set it properly there *and* recorded it somewhere for the startup script to find.

Comment: @Aaron, you are right of course. This is not a solution but a work-around.